# How do I effectively use offline documents on a WIFI-only tablet and other connected devices?

Tags: sync, offline, documents

This is more of a usability type question. I have a wifi-only tablet. I also have done a lot of documents online using Evernote, Google Drive, etc., and have tried to store them in various places like box.com.

Because wifi is not always available, I'm trying to find an effective way to be offline on my tablet, but have things sync up once I have connectivity again. I spend most of my time creating document either in M$ Office, or Google Documents. Evernote works okay, but I'd like something a little more full-featured; it just doesn't quite feel right.

I'd like to have quick and easy access to everything on my phone (sorry, can't hotspot), tablet, and desktop, regardless of my internet availability. What solution can handle all of these use cases? Does anything work well for anyone out there?

Comment: Are you saying a solution such as Dropbox, Google Drive or ownCloud would not work in this scenario?  Do you specifically need to be able to access the document on your phone immediately after editing it on your tablet without connecting to the Internet?

Answer (score 0):

Try Autosync. There might be extra charges for syncing files larger than 8MB. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.drivesync

Another option is FolderSync Lite (no file size limitations as far as I know):
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite